# Kubernetes Pods Getting in Pending State Forever

Tags: redhat, kubernetes, cron, rhel7

We have a CronJob which will run every 'x' minutes.

For each and every Schedule, A Pod will be Scheduled and it runs and it is doing its job.

Now, After 2-3 days, The Pod is getting into Pending State and now the Pod is not doing its job and not even getting into Running State.

The Pod will also try to mount a few NFS mount paths when it is getting created.

We investigated and found that the Node on which this Pod is getting Launched/Scheduled is drying out of Inotify Watch Count Limit which is 8192.

I also tried to increase the Inotify Limit using

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

But the same Issue Persists.

I tried to capture kubelet logs on the Node which the CronJob's Pod is getting scheduled.

I found the below log getting Iterated so many times.
I understood that kubelet not able to unmount the NFS path when the pod which completed its job is cleaned up.

Note: Below log is a single liner, I have broken it into Lines for a better view.

Worker Node: RHEL 7.6 (Also Tried 7.9 with Same Issue)

Kernel Version: 3.10

**Kubelet Version: 1.23.6**

Struggling to fix this. Any recommendations will be helpful.

```html
 kubelet[1784]: E0630 03:42:39.927719    1784 nestedpendingoperations.go:335] Operation for "{volumeName:kubernetes.io/nfs/8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670-infra-pv-xxxxx
podName:8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670 nodeName:}" failed. 
No retries permitted until 2022-06-30 03:44:41.927675124 -0400 EDT m=+37538.561944740 (durationBeforeRetry 2m2s). 
Error: error cleaning subPath mounts for volume "infra" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/nfs/8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670-infra-pv-xxxx") 
pod "8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670" (UID: "8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670") : 
error processing /var/lib/kubelet/pods/8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670/volume-subpaths/infra-pv-xxxx/cronjob: 
error cleaning subpath mount /var/lib/kubelet/pods/8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670/volume-subpaths/infra-pv-xxxxx/cronjob/6:
```

Failed to unmount path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/8da4fd7a-dbff-429a-a470-3c09e19a1670/volume-subpaths/infra-pv-xxxxx/cronjob/6

Comment: Please provide your CronJob's manifest to attempt an issue reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Kubelet Bug.

PR : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/110973
which will be release under 1.25 release

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).